# How to Bulk Insert and update record in mongodb using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb, .net-core

I have on requirement in that i want to read bulk record from Mongo DB A and Want to Insert and update based on the record exist or not in DB B.

Suppose in DB A i have 10 record initially so these record should be inserted in DB B. But after some time if some record are got updated in DB A and already as i have inserted in DB B. Now it should fire bulk update only.

Let me know if anyone having any idea about it using c#

Comment: Just google "cross database synchronization c#"... There are tons of solutions out there.

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of the `$merge` aggregation pipeline stage for this (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/).

This is easy to execute in C# but depending on what you need to achieve you can configure the parameters accordingly

```cs
var client = new MongoClient();
var databaseA = client.GetDatabase("A");
var databaseB = client.GetDatabase("B");

var collectionA = databaseA.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("test");
var collectionB = databaseB.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("test");
await collectionA.Aggregate()
    .Merge(collectionB)
    .ToListAsync();
```